# How to expose WTForms custom validation function variable to Flask view?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a WTForms custom validation function that returns a variable containing a hash:

```
def dupe_check(self, field):
    """
    Check for duplicate images.
    """
    def get_hash():
        """
        Get hash of image.
        """
        f = field.data
        img = Image.open(f)
        imghash = imagehash.dhash(img)
        f.seek(0) 
        return imghash
    imghash = str(get_hash())
    hashcheck = str(Sights.query.filter(Sights.image_hash == imghash).first())
    if hashcheck == imghash:
        raise ValidationError('Duplicate image detected!')

class AddImageForm(FlaskForm):
    sights_image = FileField('image', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(images, 'Images only!'), dupe_check])
```

What is the best way to expose the `imghash` variable which lives in `forms.py` to a Flask view which lives in `views.py`?

Should `imghash` go into a WTForms [HiddenField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#convenience-fields)? Should I create a session variable? Should I turn the `dupe_check` function into a Class?

My goal is to write the hash into DB during Flask view, but not have to regenerate the hash since it is already created during validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `dupe_check(self, field)` `self` is the form instance so you can store your calculated hash value in the form and use it later on in your processing.

Here's a self-contained example, note I've created a class validator rather then using a simple method.

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, render_template_string, redirect
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import ValidationError, StringField

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '0123456789'


def get_hash(data):
    # Use data to compute hash
    image_hash = 1000000
    return image_hash


class HashValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        if not message:
            message = u'Duplicate image detected!'
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        # Pass field data to hash function
        _img_hash = get_hash(field.data)
        # Store the hash in the form
        form.imghash = _img_hash
        # calculate if existing hash exists
        # hashcheck = str(Sights.query.filter(Sights.image_hash == _img_hash).first())
        hashcheck = 1000000
        if hashcheck == _img_hash:
            raise ValidationError(self.message)


class AddImageForm(FlaskForm):
    # sights_image = FileField('image', validators=[HashValidator()])
    # Use an Stringfield to make the sample easier
    sights_image = StringField('image', validators=[HashValidator()])


_template = '''
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        {{form.csrf_token}}
        {{form.sights_image}}
        {% if form.sights_image.errors %}
            <ul>{% for error in form.sights_image.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
        {% endif %}        
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
'''


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        _image_form = AddImageForm()
        if _image_form.validate_on_submit():
            flash("Validated: get_hash returned {}".format(_image_form.imghash))
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            # didn't validate template will show error
            flash("Error. get_hash returned {}".format(_image_form.imghash))
            return render_template_string(_template, form=_image_form)
    else:
        _image_form = AddImageForm()
        return render_template_string(_template, form=_image_form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9876, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @pjcunningham this technique works. Accepted as answer. The short answer to this solution was to abstract `get_hash()`, and to store the hash in the form: `form.imghash = _img_hash`. From my `views.py` I now can call `form.imghash` and get the hash generated in the validator.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can turn the function `get_hash()` into a method of the form class:

```
class AddImageForm(FlaskForm):
    sights_image = FileField('image', validators=[...])

    def get_hash(self):
        f = self.sights_image.data
        img = Image.open(f)
        imghash = imagehash.dhash(img)
        f.seek(0) 
        return imghash
```

Then in view function, you can simply call it with the form, such as:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    form = AddImageForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hash = form.get_hash()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. If I turn the `get_hash()` function into a method of the form class, it breaks the `dupe_check()` function because `get_hash` is not yet defined during execution. If I nest `dupe_check` with `get_hash` as method of form class, then `dupe_check` is not yet defined when referenced as a validator in the FileField. Also, if I did call `form.get_hash()` from the Flask view as you suggest, wouldn't that invoke the function itself and thus regenerate the hash?

Comment: @mrrg How about keep the `dupe_check()` function and create a new `get_hash()` method?